# "reflink" filesystem API for macOS?

Tags: macos, filesystems

On linux, we have the call

```
int ioctl(int, FICLONERANGE, struct file_clone_range *);
```

to "reflink" files. APFS also supports COW and thus a similar system call should exist. However, the `clonefile` API can only clone whole files, not blocks within the file, to do deduplication manually.

Is there something similar to the ioctl call?

[Originally posted here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/468652/]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, macOS does not currently have an API that allows you to clone only a range. You can use `clonefile()/clonefileat()/fclonefileat()` to clone a full file. After you have cloned the file, you can make changes to the clones ofcourse.